# How to unite dates and add their respective times?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How can I group the dates and add their respective time?

I have the following data and query:

**EDIT:**
[image]

query:

```
select distinct(date_format(initial_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) as date, date_format(initial_date, '%hh%i') as time from periods
group by initial_date
order by initial_date
```

Realize that there are repeated dates in red, I'm trying to group these dates and sum() those dates that are in green. That is, form just a date value without repeating.

Could someone help?

Comment: update your question add  the code as text too  non only  as image ..

Comment: oh sorry, i will update

Comment: *add their respective time* and what is your expected result?

Comment: the expected result is to make sure that the first field does not have repeated dates, and to add the time when the dates are joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use group by for date and sum()

```
  select date_format(initial_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date, sum(hour(initial_date)) time
  from periods 
  group  by  date_forma(initial_date, '%-%m-%d') 
  order by initial_date
```

or if you want all the time on the same rows  you coultry using group_concat

```
  select date_format(initial_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date, group_concat(date_format(initial_date, '%hh-%i')) time
  from periods 
  group  by  date_forma(initial_date, '%-%m-%d') 
  order by initial_date
```